# SQL Server trigger - get variable from the first Insert stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have an insert stored procedure with incremented Id (`int`). I'll like to take that `Id` and insert it to another table and also one of variable from the insert stored procedure.

I know you can do `select from inserted` but if I'm not mistaking that allowed you to select values from the `inserted` row.

Is there anyway to persevere the variable after executed the stored procedure and pass it to trigger?

Edit: sorry, let me included the stored procedure that I'm using. Table foo have a Id that is auto incremented and I want a trigger to insert the foo's Id and the @mid to another table after this stored procedure is run. However as you can see that @mid is not being insert to table foo.

```
 ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[foo]
    @userName varchar(50),
    @somefoo varbinary(max),
    @mid int
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO fooTable(UserName, SomeFoo)
    VALUES (@userName, @somefoo);

END
```

Comment: `inserted` and `deleted` are tables so that they can represent the results of set operations.  Designing a trigger on the assumption that they will always contain exactly one row is generally a bad plan.  The `inserted` table will contain values for the `IDENTITY` column, if any.

Comment: Could add a code sample (or maybe a pseudo-code sample) to illustrate what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inserted pseudo-table allows you to select the value that is now in the table.  The deleted pseudo-table allows you to select the value that used to be in the table before the insert happened.  Since you say insert proc i am assuming it's not an insert/update proc.  I am not clear on what you want to do.  You want the trigger to copy the identity field and one other column?  Easy.  You want the trigger to copy the identity field and a proc parameter that is not actually stored in the table?  Impossible - but if that's what you want, then you can do it in the proc instead.

1) Trigger:

```
Insert into foo (a, b)
select my_identity, some_column
from inserted
```

2) Proc:

```
    ..do main insert...
    insert into foo (a, b)
    select scope_identity(), @some_parameter
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use your table extended property for your purpose.

step 1 : define a extended property for your table.

[image]

step 2 : in stored procedure before insert into your table set defined extended property by your parameter.

```
EXEC sys.sp_updateextendedproperty @name=N'@ParameterName', @value='YourValue'
```

step 3 : in trigger get defined extended property and use it.
use `sys.extended_properties` table for get defined extended property.